# Azure Cloud Service monitoring settings unavailable

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-monitoring

I can't set the level of monitoring in production. I enabled diagnotics in WebRole project(also with performance counters and Azure Storage connection). I check azure storage tables - data is written. How to enable changing monitoring level?

P.S. I user Azure SDK 2.5

Answer (score 0):

There is a compatibility issue with SDK 2.5 that causes the verbose monitoring settings to be unavailable in the portal.  To resolve this you should be able to add the following configuration setting to your csdef/cscfg and set it to a valid storage account:

```
<Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=diagstore;AccountKey=+Pgl4GVRy01UUy9uL4cFqsufI/79xsqBAHkNmYsDycfY8Qs5dZXzqgs8AZl1XsJWvGgEUsW/smz1DvswusCxjw==" />
```

SDK 2.6 will resolve this issue.

Comment: And there is also need to import "Diagnostics" module. But it causes an error "Unable to import module Diagnostics. No manifest was found"